# how to make a child of a root new root in xml in python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

So if you do `root=tree.getroot()` using `elementtree` in python it will point to first tag in the `xml`. Is there anyway in which I can make any child of this root as a new root? I'm assuming here that any element of a xml tree can also be a xml tree independently.
Can anyone shed some light on this topic please?